# Ansible init script expect

Tags: ansible

For my playbook I'm required to run a init script which asks for several prompts (database location, admin password, couple of yes's or no's). I couldn't find examples for this. The example provided in the ansible docs, left me with some questions (?i) for example:

```
- expect:
    command: passwd username
    responses:
      (?i)password: "MySekretPa$$word"
```

How can I run my init script and insert the desired variables for multiple responses?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
- expect:
    command: 
    responses:
      Question:
        - response1
        - response2
        - response3
```